# Is Sai Baba a Hindu lord or a Muslim?

Tags: other-religions, food, non-vegetarian, islam, sai

Was Sai Baba a Hindu lord or a Muslim?

If he was a Hindu, then why did he distribute non-vegetarian food as *prasada* to people?

Comment: He is beyond Hindu and Muslim. Hindu and Muslim are simply imaginary boundaries created by people. One who says Sab ka malik ek hai and who sees all as one family doesn't differentiate like that.

Comment: It is my understanding that he never said. He was beyond sectarianism.

Comment: Which Sai baba do you mean?

Comment: Sai baba is muslim fakir but revered and worshipped by Shirdi brahmins mainly based on the miracles he exhibited rather any actually knowledge sharing...

Answer (score 11):

In the "Sai SatCharitra" (biography) of Shri Sai Baba written by Hemadpant Dabholkar, nowhere his religion is mentioned.
He used to say "सबका मालिक एक |" (everyone's god is same).
He was beyond any religion.
Devotees of all religions worship him.

Comment: Please mention Sai Charitra (edition and author) and exact verse.

Answer (score 1):

Although Sai Baba is often connotated with Hinduism but he was never associated with a particular religion, nor his religion is explicitly mentioned anywhere in the records. He used to embrace every religion with equal respect. So it's hard to reach to any definite conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to [hinduism.se]. Though you have attempted an answer, we require sources for quality standards. Visit [answer] page and  [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/5212)

Answer (score 0):

He taught us to see Ram in Ramzaan and Ali in Diwali. How could he differentiate? Destination is one paths are many. Truth is ONE, ways to realize are many, GOD is one but religion are many that lead us to HIM. He is that GOD. Those who had faith could see his Divinity and are even today seeing HIM in all HIS splendor blessing those who seek HIS refuge. He gave non-veg to check the faith of HIS Brahmin devotee. He later didnt allow HIM  to eat once the brahmnin proved his faith.(Sathcharithra). He did it to both check faith and also to tell that HE has come for all.